# EXCEL - generate a square wave from timing data

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would I generate a digital square wave from the following data? I have absolute time and the high/low level at a given time. I know that each set needs two data points for every X transition to generate a square wave graph, but I can't figure out how to do that. Time value is in milliseconds. Also, sometimes the signal transitioned more than once during a given time sample so there I need to generate some fast transitions on the graph (say 0.1 ms).

```
time(x),level(y)
0,1
2,0
2,1
9,0
10,1
10,0
11,1
18,0
18,1
25,0
25,1
25,0
26,1
27,0
27,1
```

Comment: Excel isn't the best tool for this. Do you have access to anything else? Matlab? Python with matplotlib? Edit: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28571518/6030926

Comment: just for this part --> "the signal transitioned more than once during a given time " It'll means that there is 2 values for 1 exact time.. thus.. the data is not usable to plot a graph. || If you had manually fix it, to get 1 value for each time.. then you may plot some excel graph.

Comment: is the time and the level in two separate columns or are they in a single cell?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to interpolate the data to create the range that you'll plot. An easy way to do this is to use vlookup with TRUE match instead of the usual FALSE.
[image: Interpolation]